# Did Stellar's public Horizon Server Changes its rate limit?

Tags: rate-limiting

In the stellar documentation https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/rate-limiting.html it is said that rate limit is 3600 per hour. But when i check via curl i get 101 which is too low for 1 hour. So did Stellar's public Horizon Server Changes its rate limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your observation is correct. 
[image]

```
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 101
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 100
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1
```

The 1st parameter is the total number of requests in a specific period of time (specified with the 3rd parameter).
2nd one is derived from the 1st one.
3rd is the length of period, in seconds.

.

Here, it means:

maximum 101 requests in a period of 1 second

and there are 100 requests remaining in this 1-second-period.

---

I guess the documentation will be updated later.

FYI, the older config was like:

```
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 3600
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 3599
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 3599
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It made me understand those numbers.  
What i also understand is this rate-limit is account based. What if a third party is using the public API and using all requests? I am asking this because although we are doing like 2-3 requests per minute we still get 429 (Rate-limit exceeeded error). Shouldnt this limit be IP+account based?

Comment: One more issue is from our production servers "X-Ratelimit-Reset: 60". Why is this 60 for our IP but 1 for other IP's?

Comment: Rate limit is bound to IP but not account. I just checked again and the current values are changed to `X-Ratelimit-Limit: 7200 ; X-Ratelimit-Reset: 3599`. I was guessing that the officials were making some temporary test/tuning. After several days more and the tuning should have been completed, and I think these two variables will not be changed again this frequent.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable `PER_HOUR_RATE_LIMIT` in after horizon 0.15.0.

PER_HOUR_RATE_LIMIT="0" in horizon.env mean disable x-limit*

refer: https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/88d6a1a1c1a1f04df5fab09c70bf7fdb5909a689/services/horizon/CHANGELOG.md#v0150---2018-11-06

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are confusing because when the PER HOUR limit is not =0, then there are TWO rate limits, not one. There is the PER HOUR LIMIT and there is ALSO a BURST limit that is hardwired to 100 per second.

So if you violate EITHER of the two limits, you'll get a rate limit error. See [this article on the two rate limits](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/2224/im-really-confused-on-the-rate-limit-horizon-env-has-just-an-hourly-rate-lim/2225#2225).