# I'm really confused on the rate limit... Horizon.env has just an hourly rate limit (72000 in docker image). But http headers claim it is 100/sec?

Tags: horizon

[This answer](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1849/did-stellars-public-horizon-server-changes-its-rate-limit) tells me to look at HTTP headers to determine the rate limit. It is 2 values:
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 101 which is # per window
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1    which is the winlow size (1 second).

But the horizon .env file has just a per HOUR rate and it is set to 72000 which is 20 tps.

So I'm confused. where did the rate limit in the HTTP response header come from? Are there two rate limits that determine when a rate limit exceeded error happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They did change the rate limiting in a release of horizon several months ago. Here’s some more details about it: https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/0b181590e5ad42f93be0172076717a9cb8b5d0ef/services/horizon/internal/docs/reference/rate-limiting.md

The 101 you see is from the “max burst” which forces you to smooth your requests out over the full hour and not use up all 3600 at the same time.

See https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/c0513858fa4c138f0df1ec4922de846b71a43441/services/horizon/cmd/root.go for where that config is set.

Comment: curious as to who you are....do you work at Stellar? also seems the 100 is baked into the code. can override with hourly rate limit =0. Thank you for clarifying this mystery!

Comment: You're welcome.  No I don't work for Stellar. I do have a side project: https://stellarguard.me that I work on in my spare time but no connection to the SDF.

Comment: I sent you a note on Linkedin